# dpkg: Ctrl-C in shell for examining conffile conflict

Tags: shell, dpkg

When `dpkg` encounters conflicts in conffiles, the user may press `Z` to "start a shell to examine the situation".  In this shell however, Ctrl-C seems to be disabled or intercepted, which can make using other tools in the console, like Emacs, very hard.  (For example if I want to close Emacs with Ctrl-X - Ctrl-C, or many other shortcuts which use Ctrl-C.)

I understand that Ctrl-C may be intercepted in some way because I do not want to send SIGTERM to dpkg, but there are good reasons to use it in the shell subprocess.

How can I use Ctrl-C in the shell opened by `dpkg` (or programs running inside this shell)?

Comment: why would you want to ctrl-c? That makes no sense. you should instead start your tool (emacs) from that shell (emacsclient is your friend).

Comment: I elaborated a bit on the use cases.

Comment: you honestly didn't. ctrl-c means "kill what I'm currently doing", and that's specifically *not* what you want to do (kill the dpkg update/installation process).

Comment: ah, I might have misunderstood what you want; you're not asking about using the shortcut in the shell itself (as you say in your last sentence), but in programs started from it. It would surprise me if that was actually the case there – to stop emacs from registering the key presses, you'd have to intercept them at an operating system level

Comment: I was talking about emacs running in the console, so probably the signal is intercepted.

Comment: exactly what my comment was meaning to refer to!